# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item

Tags: jpa, guice, java-11, java-platform-module-system, guice-persist

The above exception is thrown from a unit test when I add Java modularity to my project. I cannot find a solution to this exception.

I have added to MAVEN_OPTS

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

And the same in the configuration of the surefire plugin (to no avail) because the following is part of the stacktrace:

```
throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to module com.google.guice
```

My project is a maven multiproject with two modules:

```
module org.veary.debs.api {
    exports org.veary.debs.api;
    exports org.veary.debs.api.model;
    exports org.veary.debs.api.dao;
}

module org.veary.debs.db {
    exports org.veary.debs.db;

    requires com.google.guice;
    requires com.google.guice.extensions.persist;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires javax.inject;
    requires org.veary.debs.api;
}
```

Here is a snippet of the first section of the stacktrace.  Any help would be appreciated.

INFO: An exception was caught and reported. Message: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,by
te[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to module com.google.guice
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
        at com.google.guice@4.2.2/com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
        at com.google.guice@4.2.2/com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
        at com.google.guice@4.2.2/com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
        at com.google.guice@4.2.2/com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
        at com.google.guice@4.2.2/com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65)
        at com.google.guice@4.2.2/com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:258)
        at com.google.guice@4.2.2/com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:207)
        at com.google.guice@4.2.2/com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.create(ProviderMethod.java:69)
        at com.google.guice@4.2.2/com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.createProviderMethod(ProviderMethodsModule.java:272)
        at com.google.guice@4.2.2/com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.getProviderMethods(ProviderMethodsModule.java:116)
        at com.google.guice@4.2.2/com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.configure(ProviderMethodsModule.java:100)
        at com.google.guice@4.2.2/com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:344)
        at com.google.guice@4.2.2/com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:353)
        at com.google.guice@4.2.2/com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
        at com.google.guice@4.2.2/com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:137)
        at com.google.guice@4.2.2/com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
        at com.google.guice@4.2.2/com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
        at com.google.guice@4.2.2/com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
        at com.google.guice@4.2.2/com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
        at org.veary.debs.db/org.veary.debs.tests.PersistenceTest.testAccountDao(PersistenceTest.java:43)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

Comment: `ALL-UNNAMED` means "open this to all unnamed modules". Your modules are not unnamed. Try changing `ALL-UNNAMED` to `com.google.guice` (or prepending it, if you also need ALL-UNNAMED).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks for suggestion. That solved it. I appreciate the help - sometimes I can't see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that you have correct java version, use this command:

```
java --version
```

If it's not version 11 configure java to version 11. If you already have multiple java installed use this command:

```
alternatives --config java
```

and select java 11